# Drupal: content types URL?

Tags: drupal, content-type

I'm new to Drupal and I have a quick question: I've created a content type "news_section" for our site's news, but I have no idea how to access that. It says that I can access it by going to sitename.com/news_section, but that doesn't seem to work.

Any idea how to do that?

Appreciate your help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple and flexible way: install Views module and setup it to show this content type.
Other way: Apply Taxonomy term, make it required, and give to taxonomy term alias path to this way
Harder way: build own module.

Comment: I would say that Views is the recommended method. Allow yourself some time to read or watch a good tutorial. Once you know how it works, you can't imaging building sites without views anymore.